# Remove extra section or extra bottom space of tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I had create one simple tableview with section in which I was facing one issue that is, after displaying all section properly there are several dummy sections which I want to remove but reason why they had being displayed I couldn't able to found.

Here array of section count and row count under each section is proper.

So can you guys suggest how to remove that extra space and can obtain original table content size?

Below is code I done in my .m file specifically for tableview

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  // Return the number of sections.
  if (searchEnabled)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return tableDataArray.count;
  }
}
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   UILabel *headerView;
  [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:216.0/255.0 green:216.0/255.0 blue:216.0/255.0 alpha:0.5]];
  for (int i=0; i<alphabetArray.count; i++)
  {
    if (section==i)
    {
        headerView.text= [alphabetArray objectAtIndex:i];
        headerView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headerView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Medium" size:12.0];
    }
  }
  return headerView;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (searchEnabled)
  {
    return nil;
  }
  else
  {
    NSString *title;
    for (int i=0; i<alphabetArray.count; i++)
    {
        if (section==i)
        {
            title= [alphabetArray objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
    return title;
 }
}
-(NSMutableArray *)getArrayOfRowsForSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  NSString *rowTitle;
  NSString *sectionTitle;
  NSMutableArray *rowContainer=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

  for (int i=0; i<alphabetArray.count; i++)
  {
    if (section==i)   // check for right section
    {
        sectionTitle= [alphabetArray objectAtIndex:i];  //getting section title
        for (NSString *title in tableDataArray)
        {
            rowTitle=[title substringToIndex:1];  //modifying the statement to its first alphabet
            if ([rowTitle isEqualToString:sectionTitle])  //checking if modified statement is same as section title
            {
                [rowContainer addObject:title];  //adding the row contents of a particular section in array
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return rowContainer;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // Return the number of rows in the section.
  if (searchEnabled)
  {
    return [self.searchResult count];
  }
  else
  {
    NSMutableArray* rowArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rowArray=[self getArrayOfRowsForSection:section];
    return rowArray.count;
  }
 }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
  }
  if (searchEnabled)
  {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  }
  else
  {
    NSMutableArray* rowArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rowArray=[self getArrayOfRowsForSection:indexPath.section];
    NSString *titleToBeDisplayed=[rowArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = titleToBeDisplayed;
  }
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you share tableview section code?

Comment: @RealmOfFire Please check code I share above.

Comment: can you change this code return tableDataArray.count; with return alphabetArray.count;

Comment: tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)

Comment: @Drashti are you using `viewForHeaderInSection` or `titleForHeaderInSection` to populate headers? `viewForHeaderInSection` will be used if you have set both data source and delegate of tableview; `titleForHeaderInSection ` shall be ignored. Also, your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` should return `alphabetArray.count`

Comment: @RealmOfFire,@Mamta Thank you guys for your great help, I made so silly mistake there is only issue with section array return count once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to get the reason from the code(Seems like it is ok).Please check what is ur **UITableViewStyle** in the storyboard.If it is plain then try to make it :

```
UITableViewStyleGrouped
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.tblView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
}
```

and in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
}
```